# If two batteries are powering a light bulb, will the bulb last longer in a series or parallel circuit?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

I thought a series circuit would last longer because it consumes less power, but found conflicting answers when looking online and now I'm just really confused.

Comment: Do you have a link to any of the conflicting answers?

Comment: In the first link, people say that parallel batteries last longer, while in the second people say the opposite, even the question asker.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Do-batteries-last-longer-in-series-or-parallel

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-light-bulbs-in-parallel-shorten-battery-life-compared-to-light-bulbs-in-series

Comment: These links don't answer the same questions. Pointless to compare their answers.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought a series circuit would last longer **because it consumes less
>   power**

Why? If the two (ideal, identical) batteries are series connected, the voltage across the bulb is

$$V_{bulb} = 2\cdot V_{bat}$$

If the two batteries are parallel connected, the voltage across the bulb is just $V_{bat}$.

Since the power delivered to the bulb is proportional to the square of $V_{bulb}$

$$P_{bulb} \propto V^2_{bulb}$$

it follows that the series connected batteries deliver four times as much power to the bulb than the parallel connected batteries.

Comment: It also follows that the bulb will burn much hotter and brighter and will probably go 'bang!' much sooner!